# .htaccess brotli compression with BrotliCompressionQuality in one line

Tags: apache, .htaccess, compression, brotli

I'm trying to active a better BrotliCompressionQuality of 6 or 7 in my htaccess file, but is has no sense on compression. Maybe is there a special syntax for one line usage?

Here is a good working examle:

```
AddOutputFilterByType BROTLI_COMPRESS;DEFLATE text/html
```

And I am tring to use that one for better compression:

```
AddOutputFilterByType BROTLI_COMPRESS;DEFLATE BrotliCompressionQuality 7 text/html
```

But compression quality is always on default.

Test with https://tools.paulcalvano.com/compression.php shown always the default value of 5.

Anyone know how to set up compression quality to other value as default in just one line?

Comment: [`BrotliCompressionQuality`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_brotli.html#brotlicompressionquality) is a separate directive, not a "parameter" for `AddOutputFilterByType`, or anything like that. Therefor it simply makes no sense to ask how to "do this in one line."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> AddOutputFilterByType BROTLI_COMPRESS;DEFLATE BrotliCompressionQuality 7 text/html
> ```

Should be:

```
AddOutputFilterByType BROTLI_COMPRESS;DEFLATE text/html
BrotliCompressionQuality 7
```

But `BrotliCompressionQuality` cannot be used in `.htaccess`. This directive can only be used in the main server config (or vHost).

Reference:

- https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_filter.html#addoutputfilterbytype
- https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_brotli.html#brotlicompressionquality

Comment: If I'm using BrotliCompressionQuality as a separate line `AddOutputFilterByType BROTLI_COMPRESS;DEFLATE text/html`  `BrotliCompressionQuality 7` then I get an 500 error

Comment: @Astarot Ah, `BrotliCompressionQuality` can only be used in the main server config (or virtualhost).  This cannot be used in `.htaccess`.

Comment: OK, then I will stay by compressing of 5. Thank you!